# why does it use " ErrCounter >= limt " in the condition?

Tags: uml, state-machine, state-diagram

in state machine diagram ,I don't understand why the condition is ErrCounter >= limit . i think it is good to write ErrCounter == limit .

[image: there is image contain the state machine diagram]

Comment: That's called **robustness**. Go with Ister's answer.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness

Comment: Just a note: the diagram is not well written because of conflicting transitions (the conditions [incorrect] and [incorrect and Errcounter >= Limit] are not exclusive). See UML 2.5.1 standard chapter p. 317 and 318.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrCounter >= limit` is stronger than `ErrCounter == limit`. You have a gain with no risk.

This is to be on a safe side. The problem is there might be also something else that increments the `ErrCounter` while in one of the states (or even in transition) or the `ErrCounter` can be already equal to limit when starting the process (BTW this should lead to rejection anyway but never mind).

Let's make it a life example. Imagine those two scenarios (let's say `limit = 3`):

1. The card holder has already tried trice at some other point (e.g. in a shop) failing to use the correct pin. Now `ErrCounter = 3`. The card holder decides to give it another try in the ATM. The ATM reads the `ErrCounter` (as part of `Authentication`) and as the `CheckPin` failed (automatically due to too many earlier tries) now the `ErrCounter` is incremented again (so `ErrCounter = 4`). With weak case you can try again and again in an infinite loop.
2. The card is duplicated (you know, now it can be handled through any NFC phone for example). Imagine two people want to withdraw a large amount so they work simultaneously on two ATMs. The bad luck is that they find themselves in the situation where both of them make a mistaken the PIN twice. Let's say the ATM reads the current `ErrCounter` as part of `Authentication`. So we have (in brackets resultant `ErrCounter`):

   - partner 1 enters incorrect PIN on ATM1 (`ErrCounter = 1`)
   - partner 2 enters incorrect PIN on ATM2 (`ErrCounter = 2`)
   - partner 1 enters incorrect PIN on ATM1 (`ErrCounter = 3`). Partner 1's try (with phone) is now rejected
   - partner 2 enters incorrect PIN on ATM2 (`ErrCounter = 4`). If there wasn't `>=` it would again put an infinite loop of tries. With the stronger inequation this try is also rejected.

Comment: for the first scenario , when ErrCounter set 3 , ATM  eats card . So The card holder can't do   another try in the ATM.

Comment: @MuhammadAl-ealyawi that's why I wrote "at some other point". Of course probably this "other point" should stop the card. But there might be a small shop with insufficiently educated staff who did not stop the card even though they should.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if you find it the right solution?